# Rails - Find what kind of HTTP method was used in a REST call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

How can I find what type of REST call it is i.e., PUT, POST, GET from the global variable?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following suite of methods on the request object which is available from the controller: `#get?`, `#post?` , etc...

You can look here for more details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

You can also do the following within the controller: `request.request_method`, which returns 'GET', 'POST', etc...

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be in the Network tab of your browser's javascript console?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use it in my application. Is this possible? Sorry, I'm new to web dev.

Comment: I'm new too :), but I would like to know this as well.